# How to use Context filtering to show images of only other users in a user profile

Tags: users, views

I am trying to display linked images of available users within another user profile, without showing the image of the user the profile refers to.

I have used the User ID in a context filter to filter the required linked images and checked Exclude in the More section. This displays the correct images in the preview when a User ID of the profile has been specified.

However, when this is tried on the actual site all the users are displayed, including the user of the profile.

It appears that the filter does not detect the User ID of the profile. Is there a way of correcting the filtering to just show the required users?